# Configuring Mac OS X Mountain Lion to use python.org's python 2.7.4

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, osx-mountain-lion

I am using Mac OS X Mountain Lion and I have installed the "python.org version" of python 2.7.4.

It seems like this newly version is invoked by the command python2 since it gives the version as 2.7.4, whereas the default (pre-installed mac) version is invoked with the command python (it displays version 2.7.2). Is this correct?

How do I best change the command 'python' to point to the newly installed 'python2'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a shell script in the /Applications/Python X.X.
run this shell script to setup your PATH variable for whatever shell you use.

For more info check the README.txt